# Python difference between [:-1] and [::-1]

Tags: python, slice

I was asking myself what the difference is between:

`[:-1]` and `[::-1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[:-1] will give you the output from first element to 2nd last element

[::-1] will reverse your given input

e.g.;

```
s = "sachin"
s[:-1]             # 'sachi'
s[::-1]            # 'nihcas'
```

Answer (score 1):

Understand in a practical way using list:

```
list = ["manoj", "saloni", "soumya", "ankita", "kiran"]
print(list[:-1])
print(list[::-1])
```

Output:

```
['manoj', 'saloni', 'soumya', 'ankita']

['kiran', 'ankita', 'soumya', 'saloni', 'manoj']
```